# I get these weird characters when I try to print out a vector element!

Tags: java, syntax, autoboxing

I'm using Netbeans.
When I run the program below, I get this as output `[I@de6ced`! How come?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Test {

public static void main (String[] args) {
     int[] a = new int[1];
     a[0] = 5;
     Vector<Integer> a1 = new Vector(Arrays.asList(a));
     System.out.println(a1.elementAt(0));
 }
}
```

I also tried working around it but then I got a

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at TopCoder.Test.main(Test.java:13)
Java Result: 1

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[1];
    a[0] = 5;
    Vector<Integer> a1 = new Vector(Arrays.asList(a));

    int b = a1.elementAt(0); /* EXCEPTION THROWN HERE */
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: You can use Arrays.asList's vararg implementation to avoid the int array:  Vector<Integer> a1 = new Vector( Arrays.asList( 5 ) );

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040868/java-syntax-and-meaning-behind-b1ef9157-binary-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Integer[] a = new Integer[1];
a[0] = new Integer(5);
List list = Arrays.asList(a);
System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

The above works as you would expect.

So it looks like the "int" array is treated like an Object and not an array of Integers. In other words auto boxing doesn't seem to be applied to it?

Comment: Oh thanks ! It worked ! I changed int[] a = new int[1];
to Integer[] a = new Integer[1];. Thank you !!!!

Comment: This is nasty. Autoboxing is nice when it works, but when it does not (as in this case) it makes for hard-to-understand behaviour (and SCJP trick questions). Probably a result of autoboxing (and varargs and generics) being added to the language fairly late. If it had been in Java from the beginning, these ambiguities could have been avoided.

Answer (score 6):

`[I@de6ced` can be broken down as:
 - `[` an array
 - `I` of integers
 - `de6ced` with this <s>reference</s> hash-code (which, in Sun Java, is basically the reference)

toString() for Object returns somethine like ClassName@HashCode, which is exactly what you're seeing happen here just with the (rather wierd) primitive-array classes.

The problem is that the wrong type is being inferred by the `<T> List<T> asList(T...)` method.  Change your code to use `Integer[]` instead of `int[]`.  This is a consequence of int being primitive, but int[] is an object.

You can see this directly:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new int[]{5}));
```

=> `[[I@`*some reference*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{5}).get(0));
```

=> `5`

Comment: +1 for noticing that the code supplied does not match the reported behavior!

Comment: I'm sure I haven't left anything out. That's the output I get when I compile that program ...

Comment: There's something weird with generics/boxing going on there I think, I'll get back to you in a second.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out what was happening:

```
 int[] a = new int[1];
 a[0] = 5;
```

We now have an array of int.

```
 Vector<Integer> a1 = new Vector(Arrays.asList(a));
```

The problem is in the way you are calling `Arrays.asList`.

The signature for asList is  "`public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)`". It does not apply with `T == int` because `int` is not an object type.  And it cannot match with `T == Integer` because the base type of the array `a` is `int` not `Integer`.  What is actually happening is that `T` is binding to `int[]`, and `Arrays.aslist(a)` is returning a `List<int[]>` with one element that is the value of `a`!!!

Then you create a `Vector` from the `List` and get a `Vector` with one element ... the original `int[]` that was assigned to 'a'.

```
 System.out.println(a1.elementAt(0));
```

Finally, `a1.elementAt(0)` fetches the `int[]`, and you end up calling the `Object` implementation of the `toString()` method.

A couple of important lesson to learn from this:

- it is a bad idea to mix raw types and
  generic types as you do on the line
  that declares `a1`, and
- it is a bad idea to ignore, or turn
  off the compiler's generic type-safety
  warnings

Comment: so if he had written "new Vector<Integer>(Arrays.asList(a))" it would have worked? Or at least failed to compile?

Comment: @Thilo: it should have given compilation warning saying that the actual argument type doesn't match the constructor's parameter type.

Comment: @Thilo: indeed, there should have been a compiler warning for the original version as well, about assigning a raw type to a parameterized type.

Comment: Warnings are fine when the type declaration is missing, but when I go to the trouble to write "new Vector<Integer>", I would want it to either work (and no warnings) or detect the problem and refuse to compile.

Comment: Just checked: There will be a compile error 
"The constructor Vector<Integer>(List<int[]>) is undefined". I am happy now.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the int's are becoming Integers using autoboxing so you are getting an object reference instead of the value. Still seems weird as it should call the correct toString and end up with "5".

Comment: Wrong answer.  The Integer class overrides toString() to give you the String form of the value.  So you should see "5".