# What does the class class [B represents in Java?

Tags: java, optimization, memory, jhat

I am trying out a tool jhat here to test my java memory usage. It reads in a heap dump file and prints out information as html. However, the tables shows as follows:

```
Class Instance Count Total Size 
class [B  36585  49323821  
class [Lcom.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage;  790  16254336  
class [C  124512  12832896  
class [I  23080  11923504  
class [Ljava.lang.Object;  13614  6664528  
class java.lang.String  108982  2179640  
class java.lang.Integer  219502  878008
```

What are those [B [C etc classes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040868/java-syntax-and-meaning-behind-b1ef9157-binary-address

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Those are arrays of primitives (`[B == byte[]`, `[C == char`, `[I == int`). `[Lx;` is an array of class type `x`.

For a full list:

```
[Z = boolean
[B = byte
[S = short
[I = int
[J = long
[F = float
[D = double
[C = char
[L = any non-primitives(Object)
```

Also see the Javadoc for [`Class.getName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--).

Comment: [J means ?  [S  means ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12505922/34088 for a full list or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/arrayComponents.html to determine the type for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an array of characters (C)/bytes (B)/ints (I).