# ClassNotFoundException error when starting my app up, logcat is provided

Tags: java, android, logcat

As soon as I load the app it instantly crashes on my emulators.  It never use to do this before and I recently did an update to my Android SDK Manager for 4.2.2 but I don't think that was the problem maybe it is but I just do not know.

My project is saved on my C:\Users\Joey\development\LibrarySmite11

Whenever I load up my app on my emulator I get this message:

```
05-28 12:27:19.364: W/dalvikvm(6397): Unable to resolve superclass of Ljoseph/lubonty/librarysmite11/Splash; (37)
05-28 12:27:19.364: W/dalvikvm(6397): Link of class 'Ljoseph/lubonty/librarysmite11/Splash;' failed
05-28 12:27:19.364: D/AndroidRuntime(6397): Shutting down VM
05-28 12:27:19.364: W/dalvikvm(6397): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11/joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.Splash}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.Splash
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1879)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.Splash
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1870)
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     ... 11 more
```

When I look at these messages I wonder why in the warnings there is an "L" infront of "joseph", I am not sure if this could be the issue but it is just a thought.

Two other things that catch my eye in the LogCat:

1 of them is this:

```
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11/joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.Splash}:
```

Why am I seeing:

```
ComponentInfo{joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11/joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.Splash}
```

Should it be:

```
ComponentInfo{joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.Splash}
```

?

---

The other is when I look at these lines on the LogCat:

```
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: joseph.lubonty.librarysmite11.Splash
05-28 12:27:19.384: E/AndroidRuntime(6397):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
```

I feel that these 2 lines are where I need to check out but I am honestly dumbfounded on what this is saying.  I am literally staring at my Splash class inside of my project and it is saying that it cannot be found.  Anyone have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: update `android tools` also ....Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22

Comment: Is your Activity added in your Manifest file ?

Comment: @pragnani Thank you prag, if you put that as an answer I will accept it.  I just don't understand why you all downvoted so much since the titles of the 2 have nothing in common.  Also for someone that is a nooby (like me) and puts the actual error I am getting rather then the other title stating libraries do not get added have 0% in common... Since I would not of had the slightest clue (or someone else who is lost) on what is happening or to do especially since this is a globally new error.  But what do you expect, some people just love hitting that negative button and being elitist jerks.

Comment: @JoeyL I don't know who downvoted you, I am against downvoting. But don't be discouraged about that...

Comment: Re: `L` in front of class name: it's a java feature, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085889/l-array-notation-where-does-it-come-from

Comment: @laalto Oh cool Thanks for that laalto.  I was wondering what in the world that could be haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update android tools and private libraries get unchecked when you update the android 4.2, so try to check them, clean and build your project..Check this question for reference  [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)