# debug: file not found in Android 1.0

Tags: android, debugging

Today I updated to Android Studio v 1.0 and I'm getting the following error when trying to compile whatever project.

....\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found

The thing is that before updating it I had no problems. Here is the code I'm actually trying to compile.

build.grade

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "razvitrance.testnavdrawerplz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3'
}
```

build.gradle (for the project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And the activity code is a simple Navigation Drawer. 
Thank you for helping.

This is the erorr i'm getting. [image: Error after 1.0 update]

http://gyazo.com/bdf375a160b1662ce4eb0d4e9aed8f30

Comment: Did you try "cleaning" the project, and then rebuilding it?

Comment: I tried deleting and creating the project many times. I think the problem is the NavDrawer and the libraries or the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874743/gradle-project-refresh-failed-after-android-studio-update) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066598/android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-project-sync-failed-error) answers.

Generally, you will need to delete your **grandle** file and let Android Studio generate the one it thinks that it is *correct*, as it is being mentioned in the given posts. Happened to me too when i upgrated to newer version and that solved my problem.

Comment: if none of the above works for you, consider unistalling and re-installing the _Android Studio_. You won't need to install `sdk` since you should have it in a separate folder from Android Studio, so you will not loose big amount of time.

Comment: I just re-installed all the android studio itself, the error still persists. I changed the workspase, i deleted the .gradles, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Have you tried instead of `minifyEnabled` to use `runProguard`?

Comment: After 8000 thousand of hours I got it done. I changed the pathname so it contains no strange symbols. Ingeniería became ingenieria and contraseñas became contrasennas. Now it works. I just have no idea why before 1.0 it worked with #Ingeniería but now it only works with Ingeniera. Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Yeah avoid using any other language but English because it can get you in really big trouble out of nowhere. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Android Studio does not recognize non-alphanumeric symbols in path (cyrillic, for example). I had the same problem, and it was solved with creating project in another folder not containing cyrillic symbols in its path. In your case it may be '#' synmbol that makes a trouble

Comment: I'm right now using another foled without # within its name, still getting the same error :(

Comment: After 8000 thousand of hours I got it done. I changed the pathname so it contains no strange symbols. Ingeniería became ingenieria and contraseñas became contrasennas. Now it works. I just have no idea why before 1.0 it worked with #Ingeniería but now it only works with Ingeniera. Thanks for helping me :)