# "File not Found" exception in dexDebug task of build

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    D:\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\奇異果Kiwi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\奇異果Kiwi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\憟?iwi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
        at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\憟?iwi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-51286ab94e7499c7ecd0aa476d97b899efaf6c27.jar (系統找不到指定的路徑。)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:158)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\憟?iwi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-ce55b50963ad65e1327b9400909949150e7611f9.jar (系統找不到指定的路徑。)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:158)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\憟?iwi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-d623e62ecbc5d0168d8c16d5b214281abe3a28b1.jar (系統找不到指定的路徑。)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:158)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\憟?iwi\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-4970dd912b559490f230c1c9ad0babb79d453354.jar (系統找不到指定的路徑。)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:214)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:144)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:158)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    5 errors; aborting
```

Comment: can you show your build.gradle?

Answer (score 5):

Try locating your projects in a path that doesn't have non-ASCII characters in it; your username is in Unicode, and the build system can't handle pathnames that have non-ASCII Unicode.

This is actually a bug in Java and is quite difficult to fix; see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56102 for details. The crux of it is that Java's launcher uses the wrong Windows API call to fetch its command line from the OS.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this very same problem 5 minutes ago. As you can see here [debug: file not found in Android 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450881/debug-file-not-found-in-android-1-0/27462588#27462588) my problem was the pathname. Before updating to 1.0 I was working with #Ing.Informatica and /Ingeniería/AdministradorContraseñas now I must work with Ing.Informatica and /Ingenieria/AdministradorContrasennas because it seems like after the update Android Studio is never more able to read special characters.

Hope it helped.