# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' - fatal error

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have a problem with compilation of my app in Android Studio (Intelij)
I have a gradle android project, and when I try to compile it, I have a error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Paweł\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Paweł\AndroidStudioProjects\PawelFrydrych\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Paweł\AndroidStudioProjects\PawelFrydrych\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: C:\Users\PaweĹ‚\AndroidStudioProjects\PawelFrydrych\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
        at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\PaweĹ‚\AndroidStudioProjects\PawelFrydrych\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-7b4cccc642163e69ebd335478983fe19388e8a35.jar (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\PaweĹ‚\AndroidStudioProjects\PawelFrydrych\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-cc94149cad1cd3a2d74c30a18fc5b5d21d9bb1a5.jar (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\PaweĹ‚\AndroidStudioProjects\PawelFrydrych\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-fea18fe2827f1630f5537e72c6dfe4e61aa8205f.jar (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\PaweĹ‚\AndroidStudioProjects\PawelFrydrych\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-4814995344b39f255a868e2c3d5776c8b77d0e5f.jar (System nie może odnaleźć określonej ścieżki)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    5 errors; aborting
```

What should I do with this announcement? I think that I tried everything, and anything doesn't work correctly, in normal android project in Intellij I don't have any problems with compilation, but when I try to do project with a gradle, there is a more dubious.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500121/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-i-dont-know-what-happend/27510041#27510041

Comment: You're right. I've changed path of project, and now it works. Thanks :)