# app:dexDebug error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to integrate "Material desing" to my application, but I have problem with appcompat. This error apears when I create new app (without any changes) and the same problem is apearing in all  apps, where I have included appcompat. 
Error:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    D:\SDK\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output D:\проги\Android SDK\errorshow\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=D:\проги\Android SDK\errorshow\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: D:\РїСЂРѕРіРё\Android SDK\errorshow\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug: file not found
        at com.android.dex.util.FileUtils.readFile(FileUtils.java:51)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:169)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\РїСЂРѕРіРё\Android SDK\errorshow\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-7494050873a5e0db75d021ea98f22efdb2950fbf.jar (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\РїСЂРѕРіРё\Android SDK\errorshow\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-6397cce9f5acef6c37e68f9aa279873b1cef1e43.jar (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\РїСЂРѕРіРё\Android SDK\errorshow\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-933d862eb04e85e5606a443514480879d39e8984.jar (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\РїСЂРѕРіРё\Android SDK\errorshow\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-d2f6b7717e956d87797a9e0c4b44527af00b4f8b.jar (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    5 errors; aborting
```

gradle (app):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.runkdown.errorshow"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

gradle

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
    package com.runkdown.errorshow;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["File not Found" exception in dexDebug task of build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500121/file-not-found-exception-in-dexdebug-task-of-build)

Answer (score -1):

Please check Your project manifest package name and build app in name of package.