# Android studio can't detect gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I used to work with Android studio normally. yesterday I downloaded the newest version of android Studio 2.12. But now, when i open any project i receive the following message

```
Gradle 'EcoAssistant_03' project refresh failed
Error:Connection refused: connect
```

and I found that all my classes marked with red and as if the Android API's are not recognized at all.

To solve this issue, I disabled the online mode by doing the following:

```
1- File -> setting -> compiler -> command line option -> --offline
2- File -> setting -> tick offline mode
```

But that did not solve the problem.

Comment: can you look at the bottom right corner of your studio and tell me, which encoding system is used

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili it is UTF-8

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874743/gradle-project-refresh-failed-after-android-studio-update

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili actually i tried the suggested ansewers in the link u provided..but did not solve the problem...dont you have other suggestions? or can you please tell me how to revert to the old version of android studio?

Comment: what if you delete your studio and download again old version? is there any problem for doing this?

Comment: @JemoMgebrishvili yes..the problem is,this website https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html  offers only AndroidStuido veriosn 2.12 and i cant find the previous version

Comment: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/1-5-1