# Android Studio 2.2.2 installed, while running new project getting gradle project refresh failed error

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2, android-gradle-2.2

After I have installed Android Studio 2.2.2 version. when i create new project and run means, gradle not sync. I am getting this following error.

```
Gradle 'MyAptest' project refresh failed
Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3813)
at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3800)
at    com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.doCreateTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:399)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:361)
```

Comment: No. i have tried this method..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874743/gradle-project-refresh-failed-after-android-studio-update

Comment: Run "invalidating caches and restart" in Android Studio.

Comment: i tried Soham. its not workout, gradle tried to sync, but, again, gradle to sync failed and the above error came

Answer (score 0):

Try a few of the following:

- File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart
- Check the Gradle home path to ensure it is valid
- Re-import the project into android studio

Comment: thank you apmartin. i have tried method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874743/gradle-project-refresh-failed-after-android-studio-update. i have deleted lib gradles files from this location.C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\gradle\lib.. then, all sdk,gradles icons are gone now.but, i have backup for that lib folder files. shall i replace there again

Comment: No worries. What Gradle version & Android Plugin version are you using? You can find this in the project structure of your project.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.14.1 &  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

Comment: also, i replaced that lib folder gradle files to original location.