# Gradle project refresh failed for AS 3.0

Tags: java, android, gradle

[image]I am getting the error **Gradle** project refresh failed and been trying fix it but no luck with it. please find the screenshot below.

Also I am using AS 3.0

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle project refresh failed after Android Studio update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874743/gradle-project-refresh-failed-after-android-studio-update)

Comment: The link you added answers for different question @ Oquzhan Dongul

Comment: I cannot see the image you added, this url not allowed on my Internet provider.

Comment: This might sound weird but when i disable my antivirus, i didn't see the error again. Also, make sure if charles proxy is ON.

Comment: Actually, that's not weird at all. Your firewall may be blocking some ports and urls which are used by Gradle.