# ClassCastException when casting to object array

Tags: java, arrays, exception, runtime-error, classcastexception

I am getting this runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Employee cannot be cast to [LEmployee;
```

It is coming from this line of code, where I am casting the file contents to Employee[]

```
Employee[] EmpArray;
EmpArray = (Employee[]) objectIn.readObject();
```

What is confusing me is the "[L" in the error.  I have no idea where that came from.

Comment: @Kevin No the [ denotes an array in JNI. The L is a marker for where the fully qualified classname begins.

Comment: You got the exception because what you're reading is a single Employee, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

`[L` in `Java` means "one-dimensional array of objects of the class, the fully qualified name of which immediately follows, until (and excluding) the `;` symbol" (e.g., `[Ljava.lang.String;` denotes a `String[]` array). More details can be found in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085889/l-array-notation-where-does-it-come-from) on `StackOverflow`.

Without more details, one can only speculate as to the cause of the `ClassCastException`.

Apparently you are trying to deserialize an `Employee[]` array from an `ObjectInputStream`, which actually reads from a serialized `Employee` (not `Employee[]`) object.

The issue may be in the serialization logic.

To check whether this is the case, just cast the `readObject()` call to `Employee`, not `Employee[]`, and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

A quite good read explaining bytecode (and more) can be found here: http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jvm-internals/ - see table 1 for bytecode type expressions.

Interesting in your case are (Java Bytecode - Type - Description):

- L - reference - an instance of class
- [ - reference - **one array dimension**

Minor nitpick: your variable `EmpArray` doesn't follow Java naming convention since it starts with capital letter. Reference: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=58