# [Ljava.lang.String;@50f6d9ca

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, hashmap

What does this mean?

I am trying to print an array pf strings that is about 570,000 strings long...I believe that is what this relates to.

It prints out when I run my program. Ignore the commented out code; this program is a work in progress.

```
package nGram;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HashMapFun {

public static void main(String[] agrs) throws FileNotFoundException {
    HashMap <String, Integer> wordFrequency = new HashMap <String, Integer> ();
    String bookContent = getFile("AtlasShrugged.txt");
    //Remove punctuation marks from string "bookContent"
    //Split the words using spaces
    String[] words = bookContent.split(" ");
    System.out.println(words);
//      bookContent.replace(".", "");
//      bookContent.replace("!", "");
//      bookContent.replace("?", "");
//      bookContent.replace("(", "");
//      bookContent.replace(")", "");
//      bookContent.replace("-", "");
//      bookContent.replace(";", "");

    //Go to every word in the list

    for (String word : words) {

        //If I have already added the word to the frequency map

        if (wordFrequency.containsKey(word)) {
            int freq = wordFrequency.get(word);
            freq  = freq + 1;
            wordFrequency.put(word, freq );
        }

        else {

            //If not, add to HashMap

            wordFrequency.put(word, 1); 
        }  
    }

//      Iterator iterator = wordFrequency.keySet().iterator();  
//         
//      while (iterator.hasNext()) {  
//         String key = iterator.next().toString();  
//         String value = wordFrequency.get(key).toString();  
//         
//         System.out.println(key + " " + value);  

//         PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
//         System.setOut(out);
    }
//}

public static String getFile(String path) {
    // Make a File object to represent this file at the path
    File f = new File(path);

    // Do the code in the try, and if it fails do the catch code
    try {
        // Make a scanner to read the file
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(f);
        // Make a StringBuilder to create the file content
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        // While the file scanner still has a line of input
        while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            // Append the next line of file input
            content.append(fileScanner.nextLine());
            // Append a newline character.
            content.append("\n");
        }
        // Return whatever is in the StringBuilder
        return content.toString();
    } 
    // Catch any error that may occur in the above try statement
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Didn't find the file.");
    }
    return "";  // If all else fails, return an empty string.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are printing a string *array*, not a string.

This is just the way Java prints arrays. To see each string, try

```
Arrays.toString(yourArray)
```

By the way, see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085889/l-array-notation-where-does-it-come-from) to see the reason why you are seeing what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.String;@50f6d9ca
```

What that means is that you are trying to **print** the `memory location` that was allocated from your `words array` which was printed here:

```
System.out.println(words);
```