# Entity cannot be cast to java.lang.Object;

Tags: java

```
com.envers.DuaVO@5d8a2977
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.envers.DuaVO cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

I'm getting the above exception when I run the code. What am I missing here? Any help would be appreciated.

```
for (Object[] revtypes : duaRevType) {
        System.out.println("  ");
        System.out.println(revtypes[0]);

        //Printing Out DUA Values
        Object[] objArray = (Object[]) revtypes[0];
        DuaVO dduaVo = (DuaVO) objArray[0];

        System.out.println("Dua Number: " + dduaVo.getDuaNumber());
        System.out.println("Dua Short Description: " + dduaVo.getDuaShortDesc());

        System.out.println("This DUA was modified on: " + revtypes[1]);
        System.out.println("Revision Type: " + revtypes[2]);
```

// Console Output

```
    com.envers.DuaVO@2d4c8822  // I'm trying to print this object
  This DUA was modified on: DefaultRevisionEntity(id = 499,     revisionDate   Mar 16, 2015 11:36:38 AM)
  Revision Type: ADD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre attempting to cast non-compatible types. Perhaps you meant

```
DuaVO dduaVo = (DuaVO) revtypes[0];
```

instead of

```
Object[] objArray = (Object[]) revtypes[0];
DuaVO dduaVo = (DuaVO) objArray[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are casting single object into object array - here is our class cast excepton

`Object[] objArray = (Object[]) revtypes[0];`

Comment: Your code is not really an answer - the sentence is.  Leaving your answer like that will make it confusing as you are coding the error but not the answer.  I would suggest coding the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.envers.DuaVO cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object
```

`[Ljava.lang.Object` is the compiler's [obtuse way of printing `Object[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085889/l-array-notation-where-does-it-come-from). The error message is saying that `DuaVO` cannot be cast to `Object[]`.

My guess is you can simplify the two assignments to:

```
DuaVO dduaVo = (DuaVO) revtypes[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on it:

```
// for each array of objects (named revtypes) in your class duaRevType
for (Object[] revtypes : duaRevType) {
        System.out.println("  ");
        // print the first element
        System.out.println(revtypes[0]);

        //Printing Out DUA Values
        //->cast the first element of your Object array
        DuaVO dduaVo = (DuaVO) revtypes[0];
        ...
 }
```