# Why is L the prefix for reference types (instead of some other letter)?

Tags: java

Why was `L` chosen as the prefix for references in type signatures? Does `L` stand for something, like `B` stands for `byte`, and `I` stands for `int`? Or was it chosen because `C` was already assigned to `char`?

For example,

```
System.out.println( new String[0].getClass().getName() );
```

Yields:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;
```

I'm already aware of the explanations in the [Java spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2) and the [Class.getName method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29) javadoc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085889/l-array-notation-where-does-it-come-from and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442090/java-what-is-this-ljava-lang-object

Comment: It isn't. The array prefix is `[`.

Comment: Why `L` specifically, instead of some other letter? Was it arbitrary? Or did it have some meaning?

Comment: Bad choice of `Class.getName`. And it is certainly *not* the name of the class, per language spec.

Comment: fascinating trivia question, someone call  James Gosling

Answer (score 11):

This character stem from JVM internal signature and class name representation.

See [JVM Specification §4.3.2. Field Descriptors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2):

> ```
>   B   byte       signed byte
>   C   char       Unicode character code point in the Basic Multilingual Plane,
>                  encoded with UTF-16
>   D   double     double-precision floating-point value
>   F   float      single-precision floating-point value
>   I   int        integer
>   J   long       long integer
>   L ClassName ;  reference             an instance of class ClassName
>   S   short      signed short
>   Z   boolean    true or false
>   [   reference  one array dimension
> ```

The array type consist of a `[` for each dimension, followed by their element signature, e.g. `[I` for `int[]`. Similiarly, `Object[]` is represented by `[Ljava/lang/Object;` internally.

It seems, when the conversion from internal class name to application visible name, i.e. returned by `Class.getName()` was first implemented, it was implemented as just converting `/` to `.` but without care for the array notation. Later on, it wasn’t changed for compatibility reasons.

---

Note the Java 8 introduced [`getTypeName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeName--) to solve the issue, i.e. `String[].class.getTypeName()` yields `java.lang.String[]`.

Comment: Yes. But why `L` specifically, instead of some other letter? Was it arbitrary? Or did it have some meaning?

Comment: I don’t know the reason (yet) but there must be one. It’s apparent, that the  letters for primitive types are simply derived from their names, except for the one which clashes, i.e. `Z` for `boolean` because `B` is already used for `byte`. And there, `long` had to go with `J` because `L` is already reserved for reference types. I guess, you wouldn’t create a name clash, if you just can pick *any* character, so there must be a reason for choosing `L` for reference types.

Comment: `long` comes after reference type?

Comment: @bayou.io: by which ordering?

Comment: why was 'L' reserved for reference, but not `long`, which seems more natural. unless, `long` type was introduced later?

Comment: Well, I grabbed an “Oak Language Specification 0.2” and it already contains `long` (amongst unsigned types). And even if there was a time without `long` type, I guess by the time, the unsigned types were removed (when it became Java), there was a chance of reassigning the characters. Maybe it means, type requiring **L**inkage, or so…

Answer (score 0):

The "[" is the dimension of the array.  So "[" is a 1-dimensional array, "[[" is a 2 -dimensional array, etc.

The "Ljava.lang.String" indicates that it is an array of objects (that's the "L") of class java.lang.String.

If you had an array of primitives, say, `int`, it would be "[I".  Other primitive types have different letters.

Answer (score -3):

[Ljava.lang.String;

Here [ means an array. L means a class of type java.lang.String. These are the shortcuts JVM keeps for itself for identifying Java data types. That's similar to the type descriptors used internally in the bytecode. For instance, for primitives the value is: [I for array of int, a two-dimensional array would be: [[I.

Here is a very good explanation: [[L array notation - where does it come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085889/l-array-notation-where-does-it-come-from)