# What is the formulation for Java Array class names?

Tags: java, jvm

I have a need to create the class name of an array in Java.  I notice when using reflection to look at class names an array has a certain pattern:

For example for an array of array of com.foo.Thing

```
[[Lcom.foo.Thing;
```

What is the formula used to create this class name?  I presume other letters besides 'L' mean different things.  Are there libraries that help with this?

Comment: The brackets tell the dimensions (2D) and `L` tells that it's an object array, then you get the type.

Comment: Also this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085889/l-array-notation-where-does-it-come-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One letter for each primitive, one symbol for arrays, and one letter for reference:

- `I` = int
- `J` = long
- `D` = double
- `F` = float
- `Z` = boolean
- `C` = char
- `B` = byte
- `S` = short
- `Lcom/foo/Thing;` = reference 'com.foo.Thing'
- `[` = array of whatever is next (so, `[[I` is an `int[][]`).

This is VM-speak for type signatures. For example, the signature of:

`public boolean[] foo(String[] args, int count) { ... }`

is: `([Ljava/lang/String;I)[Z`.

It is for machines and not humans; it is easy to parse (you just move forward, no need to look-ahead).

This is *not* the 'class name' of a thing; the usual name for this construct is 'vm name'. Note that generics just disappear from these; the VM name of `List<String>` is `Ljava/util/List;`. It's why you can't override methods if the two methods end up with the same name, param types, and return type if you remove all generics.