# What is type class [S

Tags: java, sql, casting, gridgain

I have a SQL database in a Gridgain cache and one column of that database is a short array.

| Column name | Data type |
| --- | --- |
| Order Id | Integer |
| Timestamp | Long |
| Activity | Short [] |

My SQL query is like this.
`String sql = "Select activity from cache where orderId = ? and timestamp <= ? and timestamp >= ? ";`
I am executing following java code. Since I am not sure about the return data type I assigned the return value to an object and printed its type. result was

> XX [S@3eb7630d XX type class [S

Code is

```
Object xx = null;
List<Short> activityList = new ArrayList<>();
try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = patientTriggerCache.query(sql)) {
                    for (List<?> row : cursor) {
                        xx = row.get(0);
                        activityList.add((short) xx);
                    }
                }
```

error is

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [S cannot be cast to java.lang.Short

Comment: Hmm, could it be `Activity  Short []`

Comment: Yes, it's `short[]` - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()

Comment: This related question provides some background: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085889/l-array-notation-where-does-it-come-from

Answer (score 3):

[S is the runtime signature of an array of integers of type `short` (the primitive type, **not** java.lang.Short). The run time signature of an array of integers of type `int` would be [I.

```
    short x[] = new short[10];
    System.out.println("Hello "+x);
```

The output is `Hello [S@6d06d69c`.

As correctly noted by @Jon Skeet in comment, these names can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName()).

Comment: But the problem is `java.lang.ClassCastException: [S cannot be cast to java.lang.Short` this error. I changed the question content for a better understanding.

Comment: short and java.lang.Short are completely different classes.

Comment: any leads how to do that?