# Array Class Returns Address

Tags: java

I am currently using Java and I am trying to get my getVehicleList method to print out its contents from Vehicle[] vehicleList. However, when I call my getVehicleList, it returns `LVehicle;@61443d8f` instead.

I think this is the memory address if I am correct. I am not sure if this is relevant, but here is an example of what it should print out. Thank you.

```
Jones, Jo: Car 2014 Honda Accord (Alternative Fuel)
Value: $22,000.00 Use Tax: $110.00
with Tax Rate: 0.005

Jones, Sam: Car 2014 Honda Accord
Value: $22,000.00 Use Tax: $220.00
with Tax Rate: 0.01
```

Here is the code that returns the memory address instead.

```
public Vehicle[] getVehicleList() {

  Vehicle[] result = new Vehicle[vehicleList.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < vehicleList.length; i++) {
     result[i] = vehicleList[i];
  }

  return result;

}
```

This is what it prints instead.

```
LVehicle;@61443d8f
```

Here is my toString()

```
public String toString() {

  String result = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < vehicleList.length; i++) {
     result += vehicleList[i] + "\n\n";
  }

     return result;

 }
```

Comment: 1) Why don't you just return `vehicleList`? 2) You need to implement a `toString()` method in your `Vehicle` class then iterate through the array printing each one or use `Arrays.toString()`.

Comment: related [Java: Syntax and meaning behind “[B@1ef9157”? Binary/Address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040868/java-syntax-and-meaning-behind-b1ef9157-binary-address)

Answer (score 2):

You can implement

```
public String toString(){
}
```

in the Vehicle class

Since JVM does not know how you want to present the information inside your Vehicle class, you have to tell it by implementing the toString() method