# Reading data from SLE 4442 smart card using ACR38 Card Reader

Tags: java, smartcard, smartcard-reader

Am working on a project to read from and write data to SLE 4442 smart cards.  The Card Reader am using is ACR38 from [ACS](http://www.acs.com.hk/). Following their [APDU commands](http://downloads.acs.com.hk/drivers/en/PMA_ACR38x%28CCID%29_v6.01.pdf), I have being able to get access to the card and read some data. But am suspecting that I still have not being able to read the exact data inside. This is because, anytime my application is started,  it brings out new data. I really don't know why is behaving that way, can somebody please spot where am getting wrong here? Below is my Java code:

`CardChannel channel = card.getBasicChannel();
byte[] read_memory_card = {(byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0xA7A6A5A4, (byte) 0xA3A2A1A0, (byte) 0x00};
ResponseAPDU read_data_resp = channel.transmit(new CommandAPDU(read_memory_card));
            if (read_data_resp.getSW1() == 0x90 && read_data_resp.getSW2() == 0x00) {
                System.out.println("Data in Card: " + read_data_resp.getData() + "and SW1: " + read_data_resp.getSW1());
}`

What I get as a result:
**Data in Card**: [B@378bf509 and **SW1**: 144

Please note that Data in Card changes every time, the application is restarted.

Comment: why are you casting `0xA7A6A5A4` as a byte? this will only send the reader `0xA4`. Same goes with `0xA3A2A1A0`. Also you should output sw1 as hex, but you already know that sw1 is 0x90 becaues of your if statement.

Comment: @RobertSnyder, I saw the write-up exactly like that on their manual.  I never knew it can be that easily compressed.  Thanks for the correction

Comment: Are you looking at section 4.6.2 for that? if so then you are doing it wrong. I'm not sure how to read what they are asking but they are referring to the bits. Therefor you asked for address(es) `1010 0100` and if i'm reading the document correcty `1000 000` has special meaning.

Comment: am actually looking at section 4.6.2, that's the one applicable to my type of smart card

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Syntax and meaning behind "\[B@1ef9157"? Binary/Address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040868/java-syntax-and-meaning-behind-b1ef9157-binary-address)

Comment: @MrHeart did you manage to find a solution? I'm stuck too regarding the command to send for MSB and LSB

Comment: @Apostolos yeah I got it working both in Java and C#.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you seeing "different" data isn't so much that it is truly different but rather you are printing out the pointer in memory that Java uses as a default toString(). I can only assume that `read_data_resp.getData()` retuurns a `byte[]` in which case you'll want to convert each value into a string if you want to visualize it. If you search google on how to convert a byte array to a hex string you'll find lots of answers.

Comment: I added this lines of code and it is not displaying anything:   
`byte[] data_read = read_data_resp.getData();
                for (int i = 0; i < data_read.length; i++) {
                    System.out.printf("%02X ", data_read[i]);
                }`

Comment: @MrHeart Guessing by your information and the documentation that you are asking for a address to read from the card that is either invalid or contains no data.