# Pentaho Data Integration - Two flows saving into same JSON output

Tags: json, output, pentaho-data-integration

I'm doing a tranfomation that has two differents flows. In the end of the transformation the two flows converge and save the data into the same json file output. Verifing a specific column on result file the values are strange. They look like as follow:

```
Column
[B@3e8fe299
[B@50b541fb
[B@44b719d4
[B@7dad3c13
[B@6e46a542
[B@170d9515
```

When I save in differents files it doesn't occurs, the values stay right. Does anyone know what could be causing it and how can I solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're printing out java Byte Array object IDs. Here is a link which shows similar values to yours ([B@...):
[Java: Syntax and meaning behind "[B@1ef9157"? Binary/Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040868/java-syntax-and-meaning-behind-b1ef9157-binary-address/1040883)

Can you verify what types your fields are?

Comment: Hi, I resolved the problem changing the parameter Binary to normal on Select Value component.