# Decryption not returning correct plaintext

Tags: java, cryptography

I am trying to create a simple AES encryption/decryption module for use in a larger project, but I'm having trouble getting the AES methods to work. I've done a good amount of research, but I can't figure out what is going wrong within my code (I'm suspecting something simple that I'm missing).

Main:

```
public static byte[] genKey() {
    // Create key generator
    KeyGenerator keyGen;
    try {
        keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    }
    catch(GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    // Create random byte generator
    SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();

    // Initialize key generator
    keyGen.init(256, r);

    SecretKey key = keyGen.generateKey();

    return key.getEncoded();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException {
// write your code here
    // Create AES handler
    AES aes = new AES();

    // Generate key
    byte[] key = genKey();

    // Set key for AES
    aes.setKey(key);

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter a phrase to encrypt: ");
    String input = in.nextLine();

    // Encrypt phrase
    byte[][] encrypted = aes.encrypt(input);

    // Decrypt phrase
    String plaintext = aes.decrypt(encrypted[0], encrypted[1]);

    // Print results
    System.out.println("Ciphertext: " + encrypted[1]);
    System.out.println("Plaintext: " + plaintext);
}
```

AES:

```
private Cipher cipher;
private SecretKey key;

public AES() {
    // Create Cipher
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setKey(byte[] key) {
    this.key = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
}

public byte[][] encrypt(String plaintext) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    System.out.println("Using key : " + key.getEncoded() + " to encrypt");
    byte[][] values = new byte[2][];

    // Decode plaintext into bytes
    byte[] decodedPlaintext = new byte[0];
    try {
        decodedPlaintext = plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Generate an IV and set up the Cipher to encrypt
    byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
    SecureRandom rand = new SecureRandom();
    rand.nextBytes(ivBytes);

    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    // Encrypt decoded plaintext
    byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal(decodedPlaintext);
    values[0] = ivBytes;
    values[1] = ciphertext;

    return values;
}

public String decrypt(byte[] ivBytes, byte[] ciphertext) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    System.out.println("Using key " + key.getEncoded() + " to decrypt");
    // Set up cipher to decrypt
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    byte[] decodedPlaintext = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);

    // Encode plaintext
    String plaintext = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(decodedPlaintext);

    return plaintext;
}
```

Results:

```
Please enter a phrase to encrypt: test
Using key : [B@442d9b6e to encrypt
Using key [B@3d012ddd to decrypt
Ciphertext: [B@515f550a
Plaintext: dGVzdA==
```

I don't understand why my encryption/decryption seem to be using different keys when I only set the key once in the beginning. Am I creating a key wrong?

I've also tried:

```
byte[] key = new byte[32];

SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();

r.nextBytes(key);

// Set key for AES
aes.setKey(key);
```

And run into the same issue.

Comment: You Base64 encoded the decrypted plaintext.  The base64 string `dGVzdA==` ***IS*** `test`.  I'm not sure what the question is, the code is working correctly.

Comment: I see, I knew it was something stupid. What is getEncoded() doing that returns different bytes?

Comment: No idea, you'll have to look at the source code to see what's happening.  BTW, all those `[B@3d012ddd` looking strings are not the values, they are the output of `Object#toString()` (the "Object ID").  The prefix `[B` indicates "array of byte". See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1040868/18157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trace `this.key` in AES class all the way through encode and decode using `Arrays.toString(this.key.getEncoded())` it does look like it's using a persistent key.

`this.key.getEncoded().toString())` returns a different representation each time but it seems like the actual byte array is the same.

I replaced

```
String plaintext = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(decodedPlaintext);
```

with

```
String plaintext = new String(decodedPlaintext, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

and it seemed to work.