# Odd case in Java generics - should class level generic affect getters?

Tags: java, generics

I came across this weird case while writing a unit test today (simplified below).

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
public class Test {

    public static class TestClass<T> {
        private final Collection<String> field = Collections.emptyList();

        public Collection<String> getField(){
            return this.field;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Unchecked assignment, but why?
        TestClass case1 = new TestClass();
        Collection<String> field1 = case1.getField();

        // This is ok
        TestClass case2 = new TestClass();
        Collection field2 = case2.getField();

        // Adding a type parameter to the class makes the unchecked assignment dissapear
        TestClass<String> case3 = new TestClass<>();
        Collection<String> field3 = case3.getField();
    }
}
```

Running `javac Test.java -Xlint:unchecked` (or pasting into an IDE) yields the following message:

```
Test.java:17: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
        Collection<String> field1 = case1.getField();
                                                  ^
  required: Collection<String>
  found:    Collection
1 warning
```

It looks like removing the generic type parameter from the class variable declaration leaves the compiler unable to infer the type of the `getField()`, even though it is declared as returning a `Collection<String>`. Is this a bug? If not, can someone explain why something like this is happening? I was totally thrown for a loop while debugging a Hamcrest matcher. This was the last thing I expected to be causing my problem.

Comment: *Is this a bug? If not, can someone explain why something like this is happening?* No. It's a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Don't use raw types.

Comment: Raw types will poison anything they come into contact with, even when seemingly unrelated. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040540/why-are-generics-completely-disabled-when-you-ignore-a-parameter-type) for a similar example.

Comment: Well, that's definitely what's going on here. Thanks for pointing that out. What is the convention for accepting answers when they come in the form of comments?

Comment: Upvote the answers (and/or the question itself) on the duplicate question if you like them. Nothing else to do.