# Understanding why Java generic interface cannot loop through typed list

Tags: java, generics, foreach, interface

I have a problem in Java that I don't understand. I know that there are other ways to loop through a list, cast the object etc so it will work, but I want to *unterstand* why this does not work in Java.
I'm fairly new to advanced Java development. But I know that Generics are handled differently than in C# and are compiled to Objects or the bound type if specified. I have the following interface defined:

```
public interface Test<S extends AnyInterface> {
    List<Item> getItems();
    S getGeneric();
}
```

where Item is a class.

Some class implements this interface with a specific tpye:

```
public class TestImpl implements Test<AnyInterfaceImpl> {
    @Override
    public List<Item> getItems() { ... }

    @Override
    public AnyInterfaceImpl getGeneric() { ... }
}
```

Now my problem is that when I want to loop through the List of Items with a normal foreach loop, I get an incompatible types error because getItems returns a list of Objects instead of Items.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test test = new TestImpl();
    for (Item item : test.getItems()) {      
    }
}
```

Again, I don't want to know how to solve this, I know there are other ways using an iterator, casts or similar. I simply would like to know why Java can't handle the List of Items in the loop. I don't see why it shouldn't be able to directly read the list of a specified class/type as the generic type does not influence this list at all in my opinion.

**Edit:**
For clarity, the Item is specified as follows:

```
public class Item {
}
```

Comment: You haven't included any generic types in the declarations of `Test` and `Item`. You have made them 'untyped'.  See the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) on generics.

Comment: @M.leRutte I think the OP is asking why using a raw type like that also makes `getItems` return a `List`, instead of `List<Item>`. What should have happened, in OP's mind, is that using a raw type `Test` only affects the `getGeneric` method, which will return an `Object`.

Comment: Another Question to also look at:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040540/why-are-generics-completely-disabled-when-you-ignore-a-parameter-type

Comment: Ok raw type explaines how to get the the foreach loop to work and how it actually should be done. If I parametrize Test with a wildcard it works as expected.
Test<?> test = new TestImpl();
The piece of information I was missing was that "In simpler terms, when a raw type is used, the constructors, instance methods and non-static fields are also erased." from the duplicated question so it is a duplicate once I know the keyword :)
Thanks everyone!